# Project Atomic - Cockpit doesnt install through Vagrant

Tags: docker, vagrant, atomic

I use vagrant to install Atomic and i'd like to install Cockpit through my vagrantfile.
Manually I use `sudo atomic install fedora/cockpitws` and I get no problems.

When I try to insert this in my vagrantfile I get this error: `cannot enable tty mode on non tty input
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.`

The only sentence I add in my vagrantfile is : `config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "sudo atomic install fedora/cockpitws"`

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can try running as

```
config.vm.provision :shell, privileged: false, inline: "sudo atomic install fedora/cockpitws"
```

so it will ssh with your vagrant user and run the command so tty should be ok. when you omit `privileged: false` it ssh with your root user